# Using Rubymotion in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: rubymotion

I am new programmer to iOS technology and I am going to create a project in iOS using ruby language I searched for and I found Rubymotion. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 operating system with ruby 1.9.2 and I found one gem called Rubymotion_generator will I use this gem for my project?. I go through the official website of Rubymotion they said we need Mac OS and iOS SDK to perform with iOS, all its necessary? or else i can develop my project in Ubuntu please help me.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RubyMotion only works on OSX.

As of today, the only way to create native applications on iOS is with a mac.

You could maybe take a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to create some applications in HTML/css/js. But you still need a mac to submit the app to the app store.

Hope it helps.